# javascript name disagreement in passing value

Tags: javascript

I have this **function**:

```js
function add({ sender, text }) { 
  messages.push({ sender, text });
}
```

It's been called like this:

```js
chat.add({ username, text });
```

I can't rename, how to solve the name disagreement?
I can't understand how this work. When passing a destuctured object to a function that accepts a destructured object.

**I tried:**

```js
function add({ sender=username, text })
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but I surmise you're looking for something like: `chat.add({ sender: username, text });`

Comment: You're creating an object there, which is fundamentally `{key: value}`. Just `{key}` is merely shorthand for `{key: key}`…